# CMOS logic gates | Number of Logic Gates issue

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, nand

I came across this question for CMOS logic gates:

Question - "Draw the schematic diagrams for CMOS logic-based implementations of
f = a(b + c) + bc. Use minimum number of gates. Assume that
all gates have at most 2 inputs and that only uncomplemented inputs are available."

And below is my solution for this function using minimum gates with the pushing bubble method. However, I am curious how can i create the schematic with only 5 logic gates in total ?. Every time i am coming up with 6 logic gates.

[image]

I would really appreciate if someone provide any insight for this or guide me towards this query to create the schematic with 5 logic gates ?

Comment: That middle gate that you’ve drawn has its output high when both inputs are low, so it’s effectively a NOR gate.  If you change it to an OR gate then you don’t need to invert it’s output.  Perhaps I’m not clear on what you mean by a CMOS gate though, is OR not a thing?

Comment: That's not bad for a literal implementation of the original equation. But what if you first apply the distributive rule to convert `a(b + c) + bc` to `ab + ac + bc`?

Comment: Technically, since the formula doesn't involve any inversions, it can be implemented by a single CMOS gate -- but the output will be inverted. Then you just need a second gate (inverter) to fix that.

Comment: a(b+c) +bc will use 5 gates(n-1) and ab +ac+bc will use 6 gates(n). Gates means NAND/NOR/INV or bubble pushing method. I was able to create the schematic of the the first using 6 logic gates.